# Communication between Matlab and C using sockets

Tags: c, matlab, sockets

I have a problem in communication between Matlab and C. I created a client in C using [client.c](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c) and a server in Matlab using TCP/IP :

```
t=tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
data=fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
```

But the server receives an empty buffer and gives error at fread :

```
Error using icinterface/fread (line 163)
SIZE must be greater than 0.
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Edited: The server-client in C works well. The problem is in Matlab TCP/IP object, where I tried server-client in Matlab and gave the same error.

At one Matlab side (client or server), It could not scan the written text. where, The following code

```
fprintf(t,'Hi')
text = fscanf(t)
```

results:
       Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the
        Terminator was reached.
and print an empty text.

Any help please!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding a pause in the client between opening the connection and writing in t.

So the Matlab client would be as follows:

```
t=tcpip('localhost', 4000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
fopen(t);
pause(1);
fprintf(t,'Hi');
```